# Storing IDs of table rows

Tags: javascript

sorry to bother some of you again. But I still haven't found a working answer to my problem.

I have a good old fashioned HTML table. Each reach has its unique ID. What I want to achieve with JavaScript is that this ID gets stored in a variable once I cklick a link on each row.

Might sound easy to you, I am new to JS and I can't figure it out to the end. Could someone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: "again"? According to your SO profile, this is your first question.

Answer (score 0):

The Onclick event of what you are clicking on can call a function like

```
function RecordClick( elem ) {
    mylocalVar = elem.id;
}
```

by saying
    onclick="RecordClick(this);"

Answer (score 0):

When you create your table on the server-side you put this in your HTML (as I understand your scenario):

```
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="...">Some link name</a>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

So why not do this:

```
<script>
    var rowID = -1;
</script>
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="javascript: rowID = 111; void(0);">Some link name</a>
    </td>
</tr>
...
```

This is not the best way of doing it, but it gets the job done. If you're using some library like jQuery, you could do it in a completely different way and using closures as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take a global variable for this. U can take it into the head section like-

var idHolder;

Now in the table onclick handler u call a function like-

table onclick="extractId(obj)">

The function definition may be like this-

function extractId(var obj)
{
   idHolder=obj.Id;
}

This will do ur work, in case of any problem reply.

Comment: *"you have to take a global variable for this"* No you don't, and it's probably not a good idea. You just have to have a variable inside a containing scope that an event handler has access to. Globals are best avoided, 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `click` event bubbles up the DOM, you can do this by hooking the `click` event of the table, and then figuring out which row was clicked. This is usually called "event delegation." Something like this ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ipuso3)):

```
// Hook click on the table
document.getElementById('theTable').onclick = function(e) {
  var element;

  // Handle IE vs. standards
  e = e || window.event;

  // Find out what was clicked (more IE vs. standards)
  element = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // Find the row
  while (element && element.tagName !== "TR") {
    element = element.parentNode;
  }

  // Found it?
  if (element) {
    // Yes, remember the ID and show it
    targetVariable = element.id;
    display("You clicked row " + targetVariable);
  }
};
```

---

**Off-topic**: This stuff is made a **lot** easier if you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). For instance, the above code using jQuery looks like this:

```
$('#theTable').click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('tr');
    if (target.length > 0 ) {
        targetVariable = target[0].id;
        display("You clicked row " + targetVariable);
    }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ipuso3/2)

Or using one of the new features:

```
$('#theTable').delegate('tr', 'click', function(event) {
    targetVariable = this.id;
    display("You clicked row " + targetVariable);
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ipuso3/3)